# How can I put pointer on map?

Tags: android

My Question is that I have a constant geo point and i want to find location under 500 m radius
from my constant geo point.how can we find these location and save in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous but I will try to help you.

If you are using Maps v2 this is one way to add a marker:

```
 myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(mGeoPoint)
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                       .fromResource(R.drawable.yourmarkericon)));
```

Where myMap is your Map V2 and the GeoPoint should be a LatLng value:

```
 double latitude = 2.344343;
 double longitude = 45.203922;
 mGeoPoint = new LatLng (latitude, longitude);
```

To save the geo point in shared preferences you could use:

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
 editor.putLong("GeoPoint_LAT", (long) latitude);
 editor.putLong("GeoPoint_LNG", (long) longitude);
 editor.commit();
```

Hope it helps.